# How to make a task to call a main class

Tags: groovy, gradle

What I am trying to do is make a task in build.gradle that will execute a main class (class with the main method), but I don't know how.

I made a test project to test how to do that. Here is the file structure layout:

```
testProject/
    build.gradle
    src/main/groovy/hello/world/HelloWorld.groovy
```

Here is the content of build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile     'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.6'
}

task( hello, dependsOn: jar, type: JavaExec ) {
    main = 'hello.world.HelloWorld'
}
```

Here is the content of HelloWorld.groovy:

```
package hello.world

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        println "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Here is what I get from shell:

```
testProject>$ gradle hello
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:hello
Error: Could not find or load main class hello.world.HelloWorld
:hello FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':hello'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.232 secs
```

So, my question is: how can I make `gradle hello` work? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a bit of googling, I found a solution. The only thing I need to change is the task block. The working one is pasted below:

```
task( hello, dependsOn: jar, type: JavaExec ) {
    main = 'hello.world.HelloWorld'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There is an [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#N14664) for doing this.

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'hello.world.HelloWorld'
```

And then call

```
gradle run
```

Besides adding `run` task, applying **application** plugin will also change the behaviour of `assemble` task. Now it will produce a standalone application that can be run with a shell script.

Comment: Well, that is all right if I just want one task to run. What if I have multiple main class tasks?

Comment: Then you use JavaExec task.

Comment: Much easier and more elegant solution than the accepted answer

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Still getting same error although my class is in src/main/java/gc/migrate. So should work but does not.



apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "gc.migrate.MyMainClass"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

Answer (score 2):

Consider this build.gradle, which is a simplified version:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

task( hello, type: JavaExec ) {
    main = 'hello.world.HelloWorld'
    classpath = files('exampleDir/bin','jars/groovy-all-2.0.1.jar')
}
```

Note the '`classpath`' argument to the [JavaExec](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task. This uses subdirectories such as:

```
exampleDir/src/hello/world/HelloWorld.groovy
exampleDir/bin/hello/world/HelloWorld.class
jars/groovy-all-2.0.1.jar
```

where:

(a) groovy-all-2.0.1.jar copied from my GROOVY_HOME/embeddable

(b) HelloWorld.groovy is compiled via groovyc and is as follows:

```
package hello.world

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        println "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the following line to the hello task block:  classpath = files('build/libs/testProject.jar', 'build/classes/main'), which is equivalent to your classpath. However, it didn't work. It throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject.

Comment: Another issue that I don't like very much about your solution is manually manage dependencies like the groovy jar.

Comment: For your first comment, your addition is clearly not equivalent to the classpath in the answer. If HelloWorld.groovy is compiled with groovyc, then the Groovy jar must be on the classpath in order to use it. It is true that the manual nature is not ideal, but that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just specifying sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath as a classpath might not be enough. If you see NoClassDefFoundError this might help:

```
task( hello, dependsOn: jar, type: JavaExec ) {
    main = 'hello.world.HelloWorld'
    classpath(sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath, sourceSets.main.compileClasspath)
}
```